# OpenVPN: different users suppose to have access to different networks

Tags: linux, networking, security, openvpn

I have OpenVPN server that have access to networks:

- 1.1.1.0/24
- 2.2.2.0/24

Also I have 2 OpenVPN users:

- userA: can access only to network 1.1.1.0/24
- userB: can access only to network 2.2.2.0/24

How I can perform that?

---

I tried to did that by myself. On the same machine I created 1 CA, 1 server and 2 client certificates. And 2 OpenVPN config files for 2 daemons

Where:

- first config file push route 1.1.1.0/24 to his client. And for it's daemon it use port 1193
- second config file push route 2.2.2.0/24 to his client. And for
  it's daemon it use port 1194

Then:

- in userA.ovpn I setup `remote server.ip.address 1193`
- In userB.ovpn I setup `remote server.ip.address 1194`

In that scenario it works "perfectly" fine. When I connect from different users(use different ovpn config files) I get different networks in my routing table. But if I manually change port number (1194 <> 1193) in user*.ovpn config file, then I able to access networks that I don't suppose to have access. It's like hacking....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need if per-client configuration on a single OpenVPN server instance.

To do this, you pass the server the `client-config-dir` option set to the name of a directory readable by the whatever account the OpenVPN daemon uses; for instance you can add

```
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
```

to your OpenVPN's configuration file.

Then you add a single configuration file for each `CN` of those your users you need to have custom configuration for.
Note a few things:

- Not every user requires such an additional config; these files override the server's defaults.
- The names of these files do not match `CN`s exactly: they are mangled using certain algorythm—such as replacing `-`s with `_`s etc.
  Refer to the manual page for full details.

Now in those files you can use almost any settings you need applied for that particular client.
You can use `ifconfig-push`, `iroute,`push` at will.

We successfully use this scheme to connect several remote LANs over a single OpenVPN instance, but it's just a bit more work compared to your case (that is, we need OpenVPN to do more internal routing).